# Is it legal to use return statement in exec built-in function?

Tags: python

I want to write return statement in exec built-in function, but it doesn't work.
the code is :

```
def foo():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    exec('return a,b')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(foo())
```

When I run this program, I get error:

```
  File "<string>", line 1
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```